# create a oracle database user with no object in tablespace

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-10g, users, tablespaces

Create user Sara with a password of sara. Make sure that any objects not created
in the system tablespace and Sara can log in and create objects up to 10M in size in the MYUSERS.
how to create a tablespace with no object.is it possible to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, it is not that you'd create a *tablespace* with no objects in it - the question is not to allow Sara create objects in tablespaces which aren't `MYUSERS`.

How to do that? Set 10M quota for `MYUSERS` tablespace; then alter user and set quota to zero for the `system` tablespace.